# How to set the default line cap and corner style in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, style

How do I set the `Round cap` and `Round join` as the default line behaviour in Illustrator?
Now when I create a line the cap is set to `Butt cap` and `Miter join` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nothing selected, make the changes you want, save the file as a `.ait` template --- if desired, place the template where the default templates are --- on a Mac using American English that's:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator CS#/en_US/
```

Adjust as necessary for how your system is configured.

Comment: The Windows path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS#\Cool Extras\en_US\Templates` I believe. Though the `Cool Extras` bit may vary by version, I'm on `5.1`.